# JNLP desktop shortcut creation with Windows 7 : "cannot create shortcut"

Tags: windows-7, jnlp, java-web-start, shortcut-file

we have an Java application deployed with Java Web Start (JNLP) that does a desktop shortcut.

One client has issue with Windows 7 : in the end of startup/installation there is a message "cannot create shortcut".

With our own Windows 7 machine we don't have problems and unfortunately we don't have much details yet. But if somebody has encountered similar issue or has some ideas to try, they are welcome =)

Java version used at the client is 6u18.

Br, Touko

Comment: Haven't been informed that this kind of behaviour would have happened again, so probably not so much to worry about so far.

Comment: In general, there is related converstation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744923/web-start-application-built-on-netbeans-platform-doesnt-create-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 3):

Two possible causes come to mind:

- the shortcut was deleted. It won't be recreated until the user redownloads the application and runs the installation. To do so, have the user clear the java cache via the control panel, and redownload your JNLP.
- shortcut creation is disabled in the java control panel settings. Turn it back on (Advanced -> Shortcut creation tab).

**Edit**: actually since you're getting an error message, what I said above shouldn't normally apply. Maybe it's simply a Windows Security issue? Does the user have write access to the Desktop?

Comment: I don't know yet about the two possible causes (don't have yet information whether JNLP cache clearing would help of whether shortcut creation is allowed in Java Control Panel settings).

User is able to make shortcuts him/herself so the write access to the Desktop should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

There in ultra BUG in jnlp processing. I spent on it whole day and fixed it 5min ago.
If yout JNLP file has `href` at `jnlp` element, then it won't install shortcuts and will behave poping up warning like **"Unable to create shortcut for ..."**

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
  href="lanuch.jnlp"  <---- WRONG!!!
  version="{{ version.jnlp }}"
  codebase="{{ URL }}">
```

CORRECT:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
  version="{{ version.jnlp }}"
  codebase="{{ URL }}">
```