# Web Start Application built on NetBeans Platform doesn't create desktop shortcut & start menu item

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start, netbeans-platform

I've created a NetBeans Platform application that is launched using Java Web Start. I built the WAR file using the 'Build JNLP Application'-command in Netbeans 6.8.

I've added a desktop shortcut and menu item to the JNLP file, but for some reason, these are not created when the application is launched.

However, when I go to:

> Control Panel -> Java -> Temporary
>   Internet Files -> View -> Select my
>   application > Click 'Install shortcuts
>   to the selected application'

the desktop and menu shortcuts are created correctly.

Also, in the Java Console, the Shortcut Creation option is set to the following (the default, I presume):

- Prompt user if hinted

Below is a snippet of my JNLP file:

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="$$codebase">   
      <information>
         <title>${app.title}</title>
         <vendor>SomeVendor (Pty) Ltd</vendor>
         <description>Some description</description>
         <icon href="${app.icon}"/>      
         <shortcut online="true">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="MyApp"/>
         </shortcut>   
      </information>
      ...
```

I'm stumped. Does anybody have an explanation for this?
Thanks

PS This is on both Windows XP and Windows 7. NetBeans version: 6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using the javax.jnlp.IntegrationService (available since JDK 6.1.18).

This class can be found in the jnlp.jar found in the JDK samples directory:
/sample/jnlp/servlet/jnlp.jar

The following code ensures that the desktop shortcut and menu shortcut are created:

```
    private void createShortcuts() {
        IntegrationService vIntegrationService = null;
        try {
            vIntegrationService = (IntegrationService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.IntegrationService");

            if (!vIntegrationService.hasDesktopShortcut() || !vIntegrationService.hasMenuShortcut()) {
                vIntegrationService.requestShortcut(true, true, "App Menu Name");
            }
        } catch(UnavailableServiceException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using Eclipse to build a WebStart application. I figured it was a limitation of WebStart on Windows. I figured you can set those properties, but the user still needs to "install" the app to use them.

It's a bit easier to install on the Mac. You just right click on the icon in your dock, click on Options and then Keep in Dock.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this worked when I previously used Java Web Start (about 3-4 years ago). I can't figure out if it's a bug/feature or something I'm missing in my deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Linux, but it works as expected on OS-X. I have tested with both the Tomcat and the Jetty web container.

So, it's a fair chance that your code is actually correct.